# What's missing in this development board?

Tags: microcontroller, atmel

I came across an old development board with an ATMEL ATMEGA8A-PU . I am not an expert but I want to use this board. But something is missing in this board as seen in this photo:

[image: ATMEL development board with a missing part]

Comment: Schematic is missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is max232 ic.

Which is used to convert the signals from the RS232 serial port to the proper signal which are used in the TTL compatible digital logic circuits.

Comment: Yes, one can even see "MAX" on the silkscreen in the hole in the socket.

Comment: To add: The board should work without it, you only need it if you want to communicate over the RS232.

Comment: yes.. Michael is right...